Spring doesnt subscribe to Mono in Scheduled automatically when used cron
When i use cron like this:
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0/5 16-19 * * *")
spring does not subscirbe to Mono returned from method autimatically, and i need to do that manually.
When i use @Scheduled annotaion in this format:
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 2, fixedDelay = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
and method returns Mono, spring automatically subscribes to this mono

can u show the code

I tested this issue you described and found that the behaviour worked and was consistent between "cron" and "fixedDelay". The Mono returned from the method was always subscribed to by spring automatically. If you can provide a reproducible example, we can look into this further but so far, it doesn't look like there is an issue with spring
